# Compare two different csv files & send email

Tags: powershell, csv, email

I have two csv files that I want to compare.

first one has two headers (ComputerName, IsOnLine)

second one has two headers (ComputerName, Contact)

I want to compare "ComputerName" if they are in both files then I need to send an email to the contact for that computer.

"Contact" has the email address for that computer

so 1.csv

ComputerName    IsOnLine

PC1             OFFLINE

2.csv

ComputerName    Contact

PC1             contact@company.com

PC2             Different@company.com

I will need to send an email to the contact for PC1 only.

```
    $Contacts = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Remote_Contacts.csv"
    $NExport = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Offline-computers_$(get-date -formt `"yyyy_MM_dd_HH`").csv"
    #Not really getting what I want here
    Compare-Object $NExport $Contacts  -Property ComputerName -IncludeEqual -PassThru
```

I have sent emails in other powershell scripts but I need to be able to extract it from 2.csv and add it to the email code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it more understandable, I would simply iterate through first list and filter second list for required information. If you don't have more than thousands of computers this would work.

```
$Contacts = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Remote_Contacts.csv"
$NExport = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Offline-computers_$(get-date -format "yyyy_MM_dd_HH").csv"

foreach ($PCStatus in $NExport) {
    if ($PCStatus.ComputerName -in ($Contacts.ComputerName)) {
        $ContactDetails = $Contacts | Where-Object Computername -eq ($PCStatus.ComputerName)
        $Subject = ($PCStatus.Computername) + ' is ' + ($PCStatus.IsOnline)
        Send-MailMessage -Subject $Subject -To ($ContactDetails.Contact) -SmtpServer smtp.example.com
    }
}
```

Explanation:
We go through each computer for which we have status.
We check if we have contact details for it, if not we do nothing.
If we do have contact details, we send message.

Comment: `$PCStatus | where { $_.ComputerName -in $Contacts.ComputerName }`

Comment: Please keep in mind that `where` is still an alias for `Where-Object`. We should strive to use full cmdlets in our sample code and teach new PowerShell coders about alias and how they can be removed (albeit uncommonly).

Comment: I like this, but the only thing coming through in "-Subject ($PCStatus.Computername + ' is ' + $PCStatus.IsOnline)" is "is" I'm not getting the computer name or the status

Comment: Hm... Try then this:


    $Subject = ($PCStatus.Computername) + ' is ' + ($PCStatus.IsOnline) 


    Send-MailMessage -Subject $Subject -To . . . 


Notice additional brackets. If it is not working, check proper csv parsing with following lines after Send mail command, 


    Write-Host $PCStatus.Computername


    Write-Host $PCStatus.IsOnline


    Write-Host $ContactDetails.Contact

Comment: It means there is problem with import-csv. Try to make following test to work. It should display only contact email addresses from CSV.  And do similar with other file/columns.

$Contacts = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Remote_Contacts.csv"

$Contacts.Contact

Comment: going through the code and it is not getting anything in the "$Contacts.ComputerName"
        ($PCStatus.ComputerName -in ($Contacts.ComputerName))
I am getting data out of the $PCStatus.ComputerName correctly, but I'm getting nothing out of the $Contacts.ComputerName.

I added the write-host. I get nothing when I add $PCStatus.ComputerName or $PCStatus.IsOnLine. If it take the .ComputerName or .IsOnLine off I get the following: @{ComputerName =QJ06800034 ; IsOnLine =OFFLINE ; Date=5/10/2017 9:49; SideIndicator=<=}

Comment: Where from you have Date and SideIndicator property? It is nowhere mentioned above. You are doing something differently than you explained.  Create csv files exactly as explained in example by brendan62269 below (comma separated values), and use simple Import-Csv from that file.

Comment: OK, I got it. I will update my code to include also `Import-CSV` commands, so you can copy paste it from the start. Anyway, you need properly prepared csv files as mentioned above.

Comment: I have my .csv files corrected now. Bluecakes this is working as you wrote it. I had some issues on my part.
@Igor thank you for walking me through some steps. I had some formatting issues on my side. All is working now as expected.

Answer (score 1):

something like `$csv1 | where-object { $_.computername -in $csv2.computername }` should work

```
    PS C:\bjm\pwrshl> get-content .\csv1.csv
    computername,contact
    computer1,me@mysite.com
    computer2,you@yoursite.com
    computer3,them@theirsite.com
    PS C:\bjm\pwrshl> get-content .\csv2.csv
    computername,status
    computer1,up
    computer3,down
    computer22,up
    PS C:\bjm\pwrshl> $csv1 = Import-Csv .\csv1.csv
    PS C:\bjm\pwrshl> $csv2 = import-csv .\csv2.csv
    PS C:\bjm\pwrshl> $csv1 | where-object { $_.computername -in $csv2.computername }

    computername contact
    ------------ -------
    computer1    me@mysite.com
    computer3    them@theirsite.com
```

If you need help sending an email with PowerShell you should probably ask a specific question (like, what you're having problems with).

Comment: I thought I did. I am unsure how to get the computername & contact email into the "send-MailMessage cmdlet from the results.

Answer (score 0):

If we compare the properties directly on both variables and then filter for the equals comparison `==`, you should then have a list you can loop through.

During the loop you can filter the contacts CSV to get the email you need to contact:

```
$Contacts = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Remote_Contacts.csv"
$NExport = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Offline-computers_$(get-date -formt 'yyyy_MM_dd_HH').csv"

# Compare the ComputerName property on both CSV variables
$comparison = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Contacts.ComputerName -DifferenceObject $NExport.ComputerName -IncludeEqual

# Filter the comparison to get all the ComputerNames that were equal
$equalComparison = $comparison | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.SideIndicator -eq '==' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject

# Loop through each computer
foreach($computer in $equalComparison)
{
    # Get the contact details for this computer
    $computerContact = $contacts | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.ComputerName -eq $computer }

    # $computer is the name of the computer that appears in both CSVs
    # add code to send an email here...
}
```

Comment: Compare-Object with -Passthru (as mr_evans2u started in his script) would give us exactly object we need, without filtering for == and expanding InputObject property. It would return records from ReferenceObject, so depending on later script it might be also better to swap those $Contacts and $NExport in it.

Comment: While `-PassThru` would work, i thought it would be best to explain simple filtering on the comparison object rather than using `-IncludeEqual`, `-ExcludeDifferent` and `-PassThru` altogether :)

Comment: `Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.SideIndicator -eq '==' }` can be written in more understandable way without FilterScript `Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '=='`

Comment: Yes, it can. I chose not to use that syntax because it is specific to newer versions of PowerShell and without knowing what version is being used `Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '=='` could end up being invalid syntax that causes more confusion.